# Drag and Drop between two QTableView

Tags: c++, qt

I have two QTableView which one has 10 rows and the other is empty. I want to drag a row from first table to 2nd table (empty one).

```
leftTableView->setModel(leftModel);
leftTableView->resizeColumnsToContents();
leftTableView->setDropIndicatorShown(true);
leftTableView->setDragDropMode(QAbstractItemView::DragOnly);

rightTableView->setModel(rightModel);
rightTableView->resizeColumnsToContents();
rightTableView->setDropIndicatorShown(true);
//rightTableView->setAcceptDrops(true);
rightTableView->setDragDropMode(QAbstractItemView::DropOnly);
```

in `rightModel` I have created `insertRow` function which does this:

```
DATA data;

data.hex  = "02";
data.name = "Command";
data_list->insert(row, data);
emit layoutChanged();
return true;
```

Am I doing something totally wrong? and can someone please guide me on how to achieve drag and drop?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a very good drag and drop example in QT Demos. You can find these demos is QT source. You can also find them here [Drag and Drop Examples](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/examples-draganddrop.html).

Comment: Please link to something.

Comment: These demos are in the QT source. Maybe you can try this one http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/examples-draganddrop.html :)